# What file does OSX Mavericks look at to setup environmental variables for terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, environment-variables

I changed something on my Mac and when I start terminal by simply clicking on the icon, none of the PATH variables are loaded to tell terminal where basic (or any commands) are.  I have edited the file .bash_profile but it seems that it is not being sourced to determine the PATH variables.

I have also tried creating a file called .bashrc and putting the same commands from .bash_profile into .bashrc.  That also did not work.

Once I type:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

into terminal my basic bash commands start to work.  Then, once I login, I notice that it must read .bash_profile because my other path variables are then set.

What does it look like though to provide basic commands for a non-logged in user?

Comment: Mark your question as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I found out that I had some incorrectly written commands in the .bash_profile file that were overwriting or taking precedence over the default profile commands.  I deleted those and everything is working again.